# HTML pages linking to other folder incorrectly

Tags: php, html, linker

I have a strange problem, this was working a few weeks ago but know the situation is the following.

I created a user system in a subdomain folder like, sps.domain.com. And I use links inside the domain, in this case logout.php inside root/public_html/sps/logout.php but when I put `<a href="logout.php"></a>` it links to root, like root/public_html/logout.php.

Any idea?

I hope I was clear.

Thank you!

EDIT: Actually it turned out to be a server configuration problem because it solved by itself... Strange.

Comment: Your subdomain is a folder within your main domain.  you could try `sps.domain.com/logout.php`.  make sure that `logout.php` is in the same directory as `sps.domain.com` is pointing to.

Comment: Try This `<a href="http://<?php print $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>/logout.php">Logout</a>` Copy and paste that.

Comment: Are you sure the href value is a local path ?

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze Yes, it is on the subdomain folder. With the change it keeps pointing to the root, domain.com/logout.php.

(at)sitilge Didn't understand, sorry.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: that is strange.  i run many subdomains, and just having `logout.php` should work as long as the file exists and is in the subdomain folder.  honestly, as silly as this request may be.. make sure logout.php exists, is spelt correctly, and is in the subdomain directory and uploaded to server.

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze Thanks for the help. Is very silly in deed, I have another file, login.php pointing a form action to another php file and is working fine, in the same subdirectory without the full url, only the script name...

Comment: what file has the hyperlink `<a href="logout.php">` ? Is it your index.php file in the subdomain directory?  Its difficult without seeing your files.

Comment: Actually it turned out to be a server configuration problem because it solved by itself... Strange.